# App search API validation tool gives request time out

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-universal-app, ios-universal-links

I am working with universal app links. I had put my `apple-app-site-association` on my server root `https://www.example.net/`

It works fine for all links except  `https://www.portal.example.net/`

When i validate this link in https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool it gives fetch request timeout.

**Note :** In portal we redirect page to website homepage (https://www.example.net/)

Comment: What's the behavior of the app for the link https://www.portal.example.net/ ??

Comment: @AravindAR its open in web..

Comment: ok so instead of opening the app that particular link opens in the app right?
Just for confirmation are the other links opening the app correctly as expected ?

Comment: yes other links are open correctly

Comment: I had a similar issue when using universal links for me the problem was with the apple-app-site-association file. So please cross check the file

Comment: One way of verifying:

Paste link https://www.portal.example.net/ to Notes App. In Notes App long tap on this link. If universal links are setup correctly, there should be options "Open in Safari" and "Open in Your App".

Answer (score 0):

**This is expected, due to the design of the Universal Links specification.**

Here's why: `https://www.example.net/` and `https://www.portal.example.net/` are *completely different* subdomains of `https://example.net/`.

The Universal Links specification says each subdomain must be verified with its own `apple-app-site-association` file, which means a file hosted at `https://www.example.net/apple-app-site-association` will **not** work for any link on `https://www.portal.example.net/`. Redirects are not followed.

To fix this, simply host a file at `https://www.portal.example.net/apple-app-site-association` with no redirects.

Comment: https://www.portal.example.net/apple-app-site-association..  this path is not redirecting.. still not working

Comment: You specified www.portal.example.net. That is actually a different subdomain.